# how to set array data for the textbox in php

Tags: php, arrays

**I have home.php file and superLec.php file. user can enter `studentUniversityId` and click on the submit button. particular data i want to show `studentName` textbox and `lecturerName` textbox. I want to pass data as a array. How to set array data for textbox value.Please any one help me. **.

**home.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
    include_once 'include/class.supervisor.php';
    $supervisor = new Supervisor();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        extract($_POST);        
        $autofill = $supervisor->check_auto_fill($studentUniversityId);
       /* if ($autofill) {
            // Registration Success
           header("location:homeLecturer.php");
        } else {
            // Registration Failed
            echo 'Wrong username or password';
        }*/
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">

            <label for="studentID">Student ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="studentUniversityId" id="studentID" placeholder="studentID">
            <!--input type="submit" id="autoFill" name="autoFill" value="Auto Fill"><br><br>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Auto Fill"-->

            <label for="studentName">Student Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" value = "<?php echo print_r($autofill);?>" placeholder="Student Name"><br><br>

            <label for="lecturerName">Supervisor Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lecturerName" name="lecturerName" value = "<?php echo ($lecturerName) ;?>" placeholder="Supervisor Name"><br><br>

         <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  


        </form>
```

**This is my php file. I want pass array values for the home.php file. can any one help me pls. **

**superLe.php**

```
public function check_auto_fill($studentUniversityId){

    $query = "SELECT supervisor.lecturerName, supervisee.studentName, supervisee.studentUniversityId FROM supervisee, supervisor WHERE supervisee.lecturerId = supervisor.lecturerId AND supervisee.studentUniversityId = '$studentUniversityId' ";

    $result = $this->db->query($query) or die($this->db->error);
    $supervisor_data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $arr = array("lecturerName", "studentName", "studentName");
    return $arr;

}
```

Comment: you want to display value in textbox right?

Comment: yes. display value in textbox

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JQuery function to set value of form elements.
Post studentUniversityId via ajax get data in response and populate the data to form element.

Answer (score 0):

To create a response with array, you need to extract the fetched data from query and put them into the output array.
I suggest you to use a key/value array.

```
public function check_auto_fill($studentUniversityId){

    $query = "SELECT supervisor.lecturerName, supervisee.studentName, supervisee.studentUniversityId FROM supervisee, supervisor WHERE supervisee.lecturerId = supervisor.lecturerId AND supervisee.studentUniversityId = '$studentUniversityId' ";

    $result = $this->db->query($query) or die($this->db->error);
    $supervisor_data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $arr = array(
        'lecturerName' => $supervisor_data[0]['lecturerName'], //the "0" index depends of the query structure, but as I can see, this is a right way 
        'studentName' => $supervisor_data[0]['studentName'],
    )        

    //$arr = array("lecturerName", "studentName", "studentName");
    return $arr;
}
```

After that in your home.php you can simple extract the data from array and put the elements in the right fields as exampled:

```
<label for="studentName">Student Name</label>
<input type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" value = "<?php echo $autofill['studentName']; ?>" placeholder="Student Name"><br><br>

<label for="lecturerName">Supervisor Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lecturerName" name="lecturerName" value = "<?php echo $autofill['lecturerName']; ?>" placeholder="Supervisor Name"><br><br>
```

Hope it help you.
Marco

Comment: @Macro `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: autofill in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Login---Registration-using-OOP-PHP---Mysql-master\homeLecturer.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />` showing like this error

Comment: Can you copy the two pages?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see and understand (please excuse if I don't), you want to populate the text fields *studentName* and *lecturerName* with their respective values. To me, you code looks correct except one thing. You need to drop the line

```
$arr = array("lecturerName", "studentName", "studentName");
```

from **superLe.php**. The line

```
$supervisor_data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

already returns an associative array, which you can use in the variable `$autofill` in file **home.php** as `$autofill['studentName']` or `$autofill['lecturerName']`.

Comment: Care to share your thoughts on why this doesn't work? Did I muss something?

Comment: `value = "<?php echo $autofill['lecturerName'];?>"` i put like this, but not working

Comment: `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: autofill in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Login---Registration-using-OOP-PHP---Mysql-master\homeLecturer.php</b> on line <b>81</b><br />` this error