# how to set backend array for frontend in php

Tags: php, arrays

**i nedd to set backend data to the front end as an arry. how to do that. below backend.php file have another html tags. please any one can help me. **

**backend.php**

```
public function check_auto_fill($studentUniversityId){

        $query = "SELECT supervisor.lecturerName, supervisee.studentName, supervisee.studentUniversityId FROM supervisee, supervisor WHERE supervisee.lecturerId = supervisor.lecturerId AND supervisee.studentUniversityId = '$studentUniversityId' ";

        $result = $this->db->query($query) or die($this->db->error);

        $supervisor_data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $arr = array(
        'lecturerName' => $supervisor_data[0]['lecturerName'], 
        'studentName' => $supervisor_data[0]['studentName'],
                );   

        return $arr;
}

<form action="" method="post">

        <label for="studentID">Student ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="studentUniversityId" id="studentID" placeholder="studentID">
        <!--input type="submit" id="autoFill" name="autoFill" value="Auto Fill"><br><br>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Auto Fill"-->

        <label for="studentName">Student Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" value = "" placeholder="Student Name"><br><br>

        <label for="lecturerName">Supervisor Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lecturerName" name="lecturerName" value = "<?php echo $autofill['lecturerName'];?>" placeholder="Supervisor Name"><br><br>
        <?php print_r ($arr);?>

     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  


    </form>
```

**frontend.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    extract($_POST);        
    $autofill = $supervisor->check_auto_fill($studentUniversityId);

}
```

Comment: What you're showing here doesn't seem to have anythig to do with CakePHP, please make sure that you're using the correct tags. That being said, what you've built there is an SQL injection vulnerability, **_NEVER EVER_** insert (user)data into queries directly, **_ALWAYS_** use prepared statements!

Comment: @ndm, If you are genuine and genius man, give me the answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655742/how-to-set-array-data-for-the-textbox-in-php/43655999#43655999

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->set('array',$arr); in controller.

or call the function directly if in view By : make the function static then 
use : 
App::uses("ModelName","Model");
$arr=ModelName::CalledFunction($attributes);

Comment: - you should know the MVC structure So :
if you call this function from Model in the controller you will send the data by $this->set(); in controller

- if you want to call it directly from the model :
App::uses("ModelName","Model"); $arr=ModelName::CalledFunction($attributes);